# How to calculate the elder generation’ maximum education year in one family

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

Suppose I have dataframe like this:

```
   family relationship meanings              edu
 1      1 A            respondent             12
 2      1 B            respondent's spouse    18
 3      1 C            A's father             10
 4      1 D            A's mother              9
 5      1 E1           A's first son          15
 6      1 F1           E1's spouse            14
 7      1 G11          E1's first son          3
 8      1 G12          E1's second son         1
 9      1 E2           A's second son         13
10      2 A            respondent             21
11      2 B            respondent's spouse    16
12      2 C            A's father             12
13      2 D            A's mother             16
14      2 E1           A's first son          18
15      2 F1           E1's spouse            15
16      2 E2           A's second son         17
17      2 E3           A's third son          16
```

`family` indicates family number. `relationship` indicates relationships in one family. `meanings` indicates the meanings of the second column, `relationship`.

[image: relationship in the first family]

I want to calculate the father generation’s maximum education year in one family. 
We do not need spouse's information.

The expected results are as follows:

```
   family id      edu fedu 
 1      1 A        12 10   
 2      1 C        10 NA   
 3      1 E1       15 18   
 4      1 E2       13 18   
 5      1 G11       3 15   
 6      1 G12       1 15   
 7      2 A        21 16   
 8      2 C        12 NA   
 9      2 E1       18 21   
10      2 E2       17 21   
11      2 E3       16 21
```

Here is the data:

```
 d = structure(list(family = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), relationship = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E1", "F1", "G11", "G12", "E2", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E1", "F1", "E2", "E3"), meanings = c("respondent", "respondent's spouse", "A's father","A's mother", "A's first son", "E1's spouse", "E1's first son","E1's second son", "A's second son", "respondent", "respondent's spouse","A's father", "A's mother", "A's first son", "E1's spouse", "A's second son","A's third son"), edu = c(12, 18, 10, 9, 15, 14, 3, 1, 13, 21,16, 12, 16, 18, 15, 17, 16)), row.names = c(NA, -17L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what I tried. I thought it was necessary to create a generation variable. Seeing the sample image in your question, `C` and `D` are the 1st generation. `A` and `B` are the 2nd generation. `E` and `F` are the 3rd generation, and `G` is the 4th generation. The first `mutate()` with `case_when()` created the generation variable. Then, I defined groups by `family` and `generation`. For each group, I identified max education duration (i.e., `max_ed_duration`). Since you said that you do not need spouse's information, I dropped rows that contain mother or spouse in `meanings`. Then, I defined groups again using `family`. For each family, if `generation` is 1, assign NA to `fedu`. Otherwise, assign `max_ed_duration` value from the previous generation to `fedu`. Finally, I arranged the data by `family` and `relationship`.

```
library(dplyr)

mutate(mydf, generation = case_when(relationship %in% c("C", "D") ~ 1,
                                    relationship %in% c("A", "B") ~ 2,
                                    grepl(x = relationship, pattern = "^E|F") ~ 3,
                                    grepl(x = relationship, pattern = "^G") ~ 4)) %>% 
  group_by(family, generation) %>% 
  mutate(max_ed_duration = max(edu)) %>% 
  filter(!grepl(x = meanings, pattern = "mother|spouse")) %>% 
  group_by(family) %>%
  mutate(fedu = if_else(generation == 1,
                        NA_real_,
                        max_ed_duration[match(x = generation - 1, table = generation)])) %>% 
  arrange(family, relationship)

#   family relationship meanings          edu generation max_ed_duration  fedu
#    <dbl> <chr>        <chr>           <dbl>      <dbl>           <dbl> <dbl>
# 1      1 A            respondent         12          2              18    10
# 2      1 C            A's father         10          1              10    NA
# 3      1 E1           A's first son      15          3              15    18
# 4      1 E2           A's second son     13          3              15    18
# 5      1 G11          E1's first son      3          4               3    15
# 6      1 G12          E1's second son     1          4               3    15
# 7      2 A            respondent         21          2              21    16
# 8      2 C            A's father         12          1              16    NA
# 9      2 E1           A's first son      18          3              18    21
#10      2 E2           A's second son     17          3              18    21
#11      2 E3           A's third son      16          3              18    21
```

**DATA**

```
mydf <- structure(list(family = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2), relationship = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E1", "F1", 
"G11", "G12", "E2", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E1", "F1", "E2", "E3"
), meanings = c("respondent", "respondent's spouse", "A's father", 
"A's mother", "A's first son", "E1's spouse", "E1's first son", 
"E1's second son", "A's second son", "respondent", "respondent's spouse", 
"A's father", "A's mother", "A's first son", "E1's spouse", "A's second son", 
"A's third son"), edu = c(12, 18, 10, 9, 15, 14, 3, 1, 13, 21, 
16, 12, 16, 18, 15, 17, 16)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-17L))
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an option using `data.table`.

Due to the nature of the dataset, quite a fair bit of data processing is required to restructure it into a parent-child relationship with its corresponding maximum number of years among parents' years of educations.

data processing:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(d)

#interpret the person mentioned in meanings column
d[, person := sapply(meanings, function(x) strsplit(x, "'")[[1]][1])]
d[person=="respondent", person :=
    d[meanings=="respondent"][.SD,  on=.(family), relationship]]

#find max edu per couple
d[, max_edu := d[grepl("spouse", meanings)][
    .SD, on=.(family, person=relationship), pmax(x.edu, i.edu, na.rm=TRUE)]
]

#decipher parent and child relationship
cols <- c("parent", "child")
d[, (cols) := .(NA_character_, relationship)]
d[grepl("father|mother", meanings), (cols) := .(relationship, person)][
    grepl("son", meanings), (cols) := .(person, relationship)]

#find parents' max edu
d[!is.na(parent), parent_max_edu :=
    d[.SD, on=.(family, relationship=parent), x.max_edu]
]
d

#the last 3 columns are the useful ones
#     family relationship            meanings edu person max_edu parent child parent_max_edu
#  1:      1            A          respondent  12      A      18   <NA>     A             NA
#  2:      1            B respondent's spouse  18      A      18   <NA>     B             NA
#  3:      1            C          A's father  10      A      10      C     A             10
#  4:      1            D          A's mother   9      A       9      D     A              9
#  5:      1           E1       A's first son  15      A      15      A    E1             18
#  6:      1           F1         E1's spouse  14     E1      14   <NA>    F1             NA
#  7:      1          G11      E1's first son   3     E1       3     E1   G11             15
#  8:      1          G12     E1's second son   1     E1       1     E1   G12             15
#  9:      1           E2      A's second son  13      A      13      A    E2             18
# 10:      2            A          respondent  21      A      21   <NA>     A             NA
# 11:      2            B respondent's spouse  16      A      16   <NA>     B             NA
# 12:      2            C          A's father  12      A      12      C     A             12
# 13:      2            D          A's mother  16      A      16      D     A             16
# 14:      2           E1       A's first son  18      A      18      A    E1             21
# 15:      2           F1         E1's spouse  15     E1      15   <NA>    F1             NA
# 16:      2           E2      A's second son  17      A      17      A    E2             21
# 17:      2           E3       A's third son  16      A      16      A    E3             21
```

finding max num of yrs of education of parents:

```
ans <- d[d[!grepl("spouse", meanings)], on=.(family, child=relationship),
    by=.EACHI, .(family=i.family, id=i.relationship, edu=i.edu,
        fedu=if (any(!is.na(parent_max_edu))) max(parent_max_edu, na.rm=TRUE) else NA_real_)][,
            (1L:2L) := NULL]
setorder(ans, family, id)[]
```

output:

```
    family  id edu fedu
 1:      1   A  12   10
 2:      1   C  10   NA
 3:      1   D   9   NA
 4:      1  E1  15   18
 5:      1  E2  13   18
 6:      1 G11   3   15
 7:      1 G12   1   15
 8:      2   A  21   16
 9:      2   C  12   NA
10:      2   D  16   NA
11:      2  E1  18   21
12:      2  E2  17   21
13:      2  E3  16   21
```